# Populating a TableView with data from Database JavaFX

Tags: database, javafx, tableview

I'm trying to populate my TableView in JavaFX with data from my database. 
I've been trying a lot of different methods to try and get something working. I've been changing a lot of things but ultimately I haven't gotten anywhere. I think it has something to do with the way I'm loading my FXML file.

My database has 3 columns, so I'm not sure if I have to define everything from the database in my Artist class and that's why it's giving me errors.

I built my GUI with SceneBuilder so I'll attach my FXML file.

My main class

```
package application;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class
            .getResource("artistSelection.fxml"));
        Group rootGroup = loader.load();

    final artistSelectionController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setStage(stage);  
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootGroup,600,400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    StageStyle stageStyle = StageStyle.TRANSPARENT;
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(stageStyle);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }
}
```

My Controller Class

```
public class artistSelectionController{

@FXML
private Rectangle rect;

@FXML
private ImageView logo;

@FXML
private HBox buttons;

@FXML
private Button newArtist;

@FXML
private Button closeScreen;

private Stage stage;
private double dragAnchorX;
private double dragAnchorY;

private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

public void setStage(Stage stage){
    this.stage = stage;
}

@FXML
public void closeScreenHandler(ActionEvent e){
    stage.close();
}

@FXML
public void mousePressedHandler(MouseEvent me) {
    dragAnchorX = me.getScreenX() - stage.getX();
    dragAnchorY = me.getScreenY() - stage.getY();
    }

@FXML
public void mouseDraggedHandler(MouseEvent me) {
    stage.setX(me.getScreenX() - dragAnchorX);
    stage.setY(me.getScreenY() - dragAnchorY);
    }

@FXML
private static TableView<Artist> artistTable;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Artist, String> artistName;

private DBConnect objDbClass;

private Connection con;

private Logger logger;

@FXML
void initialize(){
    // assert artistTable != null : "fx:id=\"tableview\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'UserMaster.fxml'.";
     artistName.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Artist,String>("Artist"));        

    objDbClass = new DBConnect();
    try{
        con = objDbClass.getConnection();
        buildData();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
        logger.newInput(ce.toString());
    }
    catch(SQLException ce){
        logger.newInput(ce.toString());
    }
}

private ObservableList<Artist> data;

public void buildData(){        
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try{      
        String SQL = "Select Name from ARTIST";            
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);  
        while(rs.next()){
            Artist cm = new Artist();                     

            cm.name.set(rs.getString("name"));

            data.add(cm);                  
        }
        artistTable.setItems(data);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("Error on Building Data");            
    }
}


}
```

My POJO

```
package application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Artist {

public SimpleStringProperty name =  new SimpleStringProperty();
public SimpleStringProperty genre = new SimpleStringProperty();

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre.get();
}   
}
```

My Database Connector

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect{    
public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{       
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/myStudio","root","root"); 
    }
}
```

And finally my FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<Group fx:id="rootGroup" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application/artistSelectionController">
<children>
  <Rectangle fx:id="rect" arcHeight="50.0" arcWidth="50.0" height="376.0" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="13.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="577.0">
     <fill>
        <LinearGradient cycleMethod="REPEAT" endX="1.0" endY="1.0" startY="1.0">
           <stops>
              <Stop color="#1b2f36" />
              <Stop color="#1b2f36" offset="0.007662835249042145" />
              <Stop color="#15596e" offset="1.0" />
           </stops>
        </LinearGradient>
     </fill>
  </Rectangle>
  <ImageView fx:id="logo" fitHeight="411.0" fitWidth="606.0" layoutX="13.0" layoutY="13.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
     <image>
        <Image url="@../../../../Downloads/myStudio.png" />
     </image>
  </ImageView>
  <TableView fx:id="artistTable" layoutX="316.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="223.0" prefWidth="241.0">
     <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="artistName" editable="false" prefWidth="240.0" resizable="false" text="Artists" />
     </columns>
  </TableView>
  <HBox fx:id="buttons" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="339.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="20.0">
     <children>
        <Button fx:id="newArtist" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="New Artist" />
        <Button fx:id="closeScreen" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Close" />
     </children>
  </HBox>
</children>
</Group>
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of errors? Any Stacktrace? What exactly is the question?

Comment: @eckig I've been getting exception errors mainly. The main question is how do I populate my tableview with the data from my database?

Comment: Then you should post the stack trace, and identify the lines that are causing the exception. Which part isn't working: getting the data from the database, or populating the table with it?

Comment: @James_D This is the beginning of the stack trace. I guess it's having trouble getting the data? Is there an easier way to post all of it, if necessary?

java.lang.NullPointerException
Error on Building Data
 at application.artistSelectionController.buildData(artistSelectionController.java:133)
 at application.artistSelectionController.initialize(artistSelectionController.java:109)

Comment: @James_D the code that those lines are on, is the buildData() method and artistTable.setItems(data); to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be many errors in your code.

First, you have made `artistTable` `static`. Don't do this - it makes no sense at all, and static fields won't be injected by the `FXMLLoader`. This is why you are getting the null pointer exception.

Second, the value you pass to the `PropertyValueFactory` ("Artist") does not match the name of any property in your model class Artist. (I.e. there is no `ArtistProperty()` method and no `getArtist()` method).

You probably want

```
artistName.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<Artist,String>("name"));
```

which will tie the value for the column to the `getName()` method. See the [`PropertyValueFactory` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) for a description of how it works.

(You should probably define your POJO according to the JavaFX Property pattern described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107). However just having a `get...()` method will work.)

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much. Getting rid of static made it work, I changed the PropertyValueFactory originally when you posted it too. I changed the way my POJO was defined like you said. Thanks again!